# AWS RDS t2.medium CPU credits low although CPU not high

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm wrapping my head around this issue with the CPU Balance constantly going down although my CPU during this time is <40% consistently.

I'm using a t2.medium with MySQL and according to this page, shouldn't it be that if I'm <40%, my CPU Credits will increase?

Ref: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/t2-instances.html

[image: CPU <40%, Credits depleting]

Comment: note another relevant graph is the CPU credit usage.

Comment: Thanks tedder42, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The baseline performance of a t2.medium is 40% CPU utilization **on a scale of 0% to 200%**, because the machine has 2 cores.

On a scale of 0% to 100%, like the one shown in Cloudwatch, it's 20%.

This can be illustrated with the following calculations:

A single core running at 100% consumes 60 credits per hour (1 credit per minute).  This is the definition of a CPU credit.

> One CPU credit is equal to one vCPU running at 100% utilization for one minute. Other combinations of vCPUs, utilization, and time are also equal to one CPU credit; for example, one vCPU running at 50% utilization for two minutes or two vCPUs running at 25% utilization for two minutes.

Two cores both running at 100% consume 120 credits per hour (1 credit per minute per core = 2 credits per minute).

A t2.medium earns 24 credits per hour.

The baseline performance is directly related to the rate at which credits are earned... and 24 credits means 24 minutes of 100% utilization of **one** core.

Therefore, the maximum *sustained* utilization to prevent the balance from continually approaching zero is one of these:

- 24 ÷ 60 = 40% (one core using this much, the other core idle)
- 24 ÷ 120 = 20% (both cores using this much, each)

...or any combination, such as 10% of one core and 30% of the other.

If this gives you the impression that there's something disingenuous going on... there isn't: the baseline of the t2.small (a single core machine) is 20% of 1 core.  The baseline of the t2.medium (at twice the price) is twice that much -- 40% **of 1 core** or 20% each of 2 cores.

Comment: Also potentially noteworthy for those who are familiarizing themselves with the t2 instance class: the most recently earned credits are used first, and this fact is potentially more noteworthy than it might at first appear -- it has an impact on the way the balance recovers after each burst -- the behavior will not appear to be as expected, but is actually correct and consistent with the documentation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32289481/1695906

Comment: Super useful, thanks! Would be worth updating with regard to the T3 "unlimited mode"?

Answer (score 0):

The credits are used when the CPU spikes

Perhaps you are getting spikes that are too short lived to show up on the cpu graph but which are draining your credits

I would suggest using a larger instance type with more ram.  With only 1 or 2 connections the system shouldn't be even going up to 40%.  It might be swapping activity that is affecting the CPU use

What does the swap usage show?  I am guessing that some swap is being used and this is what is making your systems performance less than ideal

Comment: Thank you for the input. Swap is 0 (flat dead) constantly for the past 3 days.

Comment: Also you are correct, there are some small spikes for a very limited period of time when it goes above 40%, I'm guessing that considers an entire hour as "over the limit"?