# AWS RDS wrong CPU credit balance issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I found some strange behavior on AWS RDS service with db.t2.medium instances. As we get from the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/36693157/3231055, the t2 medium "stable" cpu load is 20%, which means that if cpu load is less than this value - cpu credit should grow. However for me it stopped working after a little while after I created an instance.

[image]

On the first picture you can see that cpu load of a db.t2.medium instance from RDS monitoring tool, as you can see it's less than 20% almost everywhere.

[image]

On the second image - sum of cpu credit usage per hour. As stated in http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide//t2-instances.html , t2.medium should get 24 cpu credits per hour, so my instance spends less than that value.

[image]

And now the mystical plot - the actual cpu balance. As you can see, in the beginning it grows, which is expected, since we use less cpu credits, than t2.medium should generate each hour, however sometime after it began to decrease despite the cpu credit usage, which remained almost the same as at the beginning and which value is less than t2.medium generation!

It seems that +24 cpu credits per hour for t2.medium was simply turned off. Could someone explain me if this behavior is a bug or am I missed something important?

Comment: [Read through this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32289481/1695906).  Every 5 minutes, you spend credits, you earn credits, but credits are also expiring if you have credits unspent from 24 hours ago.  You don't use *oldest* credits first -- you use *newest* credits first, as I described.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot that was perfect! Thx for your explanation.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it.  Don't forget to upvote useful answers.