# Calculate EC2 CPU Credit Usage and Credit Balance

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have an AWS EC2 t2 micro.  CPU Credit Usage shows that I am using 1.1 credit every hour (use the summation stats). But Credit Balance shows a 0.5 credit decrease per hour.

My understanding is that micro instance will earn 3 credits per hour. So the balance should only decrease if the credit usage is more than 3 per hour.

However I am only using 1.1 credit per hour. Why does the balance decrease?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EC2 t2.medium burstable credit "savings" calcuation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32256886/ec2-t2-medium-burstable-credit-savings-calcuation)

Comment: I've linked to a question of which this one is a possible duplicate, where I explain how credit balances work.  If your instance was idle 24 hours ago,  credits earned back then were expiring just now, canceling out the new credits you just earned.  24 hours from now, that won't be true, since you weren't idle just  now, so this behavior won't occur in the same way or to the same extent at the same time tomorrow.  t2 instances favor not only burstable workloads, but also cyclical ones, because the newest credits are spent first, not last.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS has answer for this:

> For example, if a t2.small instance had a CPU utilization of 5% for the hour, it would have used 3 CPU credits (5% of 60 minutes), but it would have earned 12 CPU credits during the hour, so the difference of 9 CPU credits would be added to the CPU credit balance. Any CPU credits in the balance that reached their 24 hour expiration date during that time (which could be as many as 12 credits if the instance was completely idle 24 hours ago) would also be removed from the balance. If the amount of credits expired is greater than those earned, the credit balance will go down; conversely, if the amount of credits expired is fewer than those earned, the credit balance will go up.

See link: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/t2-instances.html