# Changing steal rates on AWS EC2 t2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, virtual-machine, ubuntu-16.04, virtualization

As per my understanding, the hypervisor on `AWS` will start `stealing` cycles from `t2` instances once the credits for the instance (earned and startup credits) are exhausted.

For some experiments I am doing, I need to have my `t2` instances have cycles stolen from them by default. This can be done in one of 2 ways:

1. Have the `t2` instance boot with no credits.
2. Configure the OS on the instance to sacrifice cycles to the hypervisor at some configurable rate. (say 50% of all cycles)

I am using the Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS AMI (`ami-759bc50a`).

How can I do any one/both of these things? Is there another strategy to do this?

Comment: I used [`lookbusy`](http://www.devin.com/lookbusy/) to deliberately drain the credit balance at arbitrary rates back when I wrote [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32289481/1695906).  I suspect draining the balance and letting the hypervisor behave as it will in that condition is the only viable approach... or, at least, the most realistic one.

Comment: Thanks! This is great.